# Traced polygon on QGIS plots miles away from origin

Tags: qgis, snapping, trace

I am trying to trace a number of polygons in QGIS but having difficulties. Once I select the second vertices it creates a point hundreds of miles away!
I have tried to create a new project and also exporting the land parcel file as a shapefile and used that but I get the same results. Even when I trace polygons already created I get the same outcome.

Can you help me please?

[image]

Comment: Hi Andrew, have you checked that the project and the data is in the same CRS? If yes, did you checked the settings of the tracing option? Sometimes there is an custom offset defined. If you checked this and the issue still exists, can you give me further information about the used QGIS version, the kind of polygon you used (multipart/singlepart) and your used crs?

Comment: thank you thats done the trick!

Comment: No problem, I am glad I could help